# Swagger you don't send parameters in Get method in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have spring mvc controller that have a method. This method get some parameter. I configure swagger and using swagger for test a request.When I want to try request parameter it does not send.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listGrid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public QueryResult<ActionViewModel> list(String searchFilter, String order,
                    int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
    return actionService.getAllGridList(new SearchOption(searchFilter, 
                order, pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

curl that generate for request by swagger is this

```
 curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: */*' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 792a553e-b371-48a9-b031-12b634de4ce6' **-d '1'** 'http://localhost:8086/api/security/action/listGrid'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try it adding the requestParam annotation in each paramaters?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listGrid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public QueryResult<ActionViewModel> list(
    @RequestParam String searchFilter,
    @RequestParam String order, 
    @RequestParam int pageNumber,
    @RequestParam int pageSize) {
    // body
}
```

Comment: thanks that correct.i have more than 100 controller that donot have @RequestParam how can solve this problem without adding this annotation

Comment: The trick works, but I agree that's annoying. Isn't there another way?